# SQL: Store categories counter per localities

Tags: sql, postgresql, counter

Our system is a basic list of `articles`. Each `articles` belongs to a given `category` and a given `locality`. When users comes to our application, they select a locality to begin with.
A simple reprensentation of our structure would look like this:

**Categories table**

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          id         |       Name       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |       Bike       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |      Garden      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

**Localities table**

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          id         |       Name       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |     New York     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |       Paris      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

**Articles table**

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          id         |       Name       |    Category ID   |    Locality ID   |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |   Super title    |         2        |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |   Eiffel Tour    |         1        |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

---

For our needs, we now need to display how many `articles` there is per `category` for a selected `locality`. How would one approach this ? How would you store it at the database level ? How would it be efficient ? (we have more than 400 categories and around 200 localities)
We are thinking about using a JSON column (Postgres):

```
{
  "New York": {
    "Bike": 0,
    "Garden": 1
  },
  "Paris": {
    "Bike": 1,
    "Garden": 0
  }
}
```

but are not sure yet if this is the best way to handle this.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a "count+group by" query for me:

```
SELECT Category_ID, COUNT(*) 
FROM Articles_table 
GROUP BY Category_ID;
```

To avoid the sub consulting you could try some left join.

```
SELECT Categories_table.Name, COUNT(Articles_table.Category_ID)
FROM Articles_table
LEFT JOIN Categories_table 
ON Articles_table.Category_ID = Categories_table.ID
GROUP BY Categories_table.Name;
```

### Edit

I forgot the location ID condition. Let's suppose the selected location is number id = 2:

```
SELECT Categories_table.Name, COUNT(Articles_table.Category_ID)
FROM Articles_table
LEFT JOIN Categories_table 
ON Articles_table.Category_ID = Categories_table.ID
WHERE Articles_table.Locality_ID = 2
GROUP BY Categories_table.Name;
```

If it does not work try (less efficient):

```
SELECT Categories_table.Name, COUNT(Articles_table.Category_ID)
FROM Articles_table
LEFT JOIN Categories_table 
ON Articles_table.Category_ID = Categories_table.ID
AND Articles_table.Locality_ID = 2
GROUP BY Categories_table.Name;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. However, our problem is not so simple because it has to depends on `localities`. We want to know how many `articles` there is on all `categories` **for a specific** `locality` (the JSON I shared represent a small version of what we need to get at the end)

Comment: Hi, I have just edited my answer please could you check it out?

Comment: Thanks for your update. It is fine and I actually also did it before but we also need to have the counts at 0, not just the one that exists. The goal here is to store it somewhere for fast access (too expensive to call it each time)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `cross join` to generate the rows and then a `left join` to fill in the results:

```
select l.name, c.name, count(a.id)
from localities l cross join
     categories c left join
     articles a
     on a.locality_id = l.id and a.category_id = c.id
group by c.name, l.name;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It is very close from what we want as results. However, the counter are all displaying 0 while we should have some results. I'll try to tweak the query to get it

Comment: @lkartono . . . That would occur if the `JOIN` conditions were not correct.  Check those.